# Stream a dynamic playlist to a RTMP server

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, rtmp, playlist

My goal is to stream a dynamic playlist of video to Twitch.

The problem is while I stream a file, I don't know which will be the next until the end of the current one.

My playlist is a very simple queue in Redis.

My architecture is basically (pseudo code):

```
loop
    $current = get_next_video_from_redis_queue()
    ffmpeg $current > twitch
end
```

It works but my stream player stop/start/buffer between each video so I can't use it, I need to concat videos before streaming them but FFmpeg seems to not be able to do that.

My new idea is to cheat:

```
ffmpeg udp://127.0.0.1 > Twitch &

loop
    $current = get_next_video_from_redis_queue()
    ffmpeg $current > udp://127.0.0.1
end
```

It's seems to work but now I need a tons of tests and tunning to have something good.

Before I do that, there is a better way? Maybe with another software?
My only prerequisite is to create a software headless solution.

--Nico

Comment: Would it be worth looking into continuously piping the files into a .FFM file in real-time with one instance of FFmpeg and reading from it and pushing to your encoder with another? .FFM files are designed for 'infinite' video segments... :)

Comment: It seems only FFserver is able to write in a FFM file, so you suggests to drop the UDP thing and just put a FFserver between my FFmpegs?

I will give it a try tonight but I don't think I will have a true concatenation, I'll tell you :) .

Thanks anyway :) .